# Supervisord inconsistent ENV expansion

Tags: supervisord

I am attempting to use ENV expansion in my configuration file. This `[program:test]` chunk works just fine, and the empty files `/tmp/test_0_2` and `/tmp/test_1_2` are created. I'm using supervisord version=4.2.5.

```
[program:test]
command=touch /tmp/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s
directory=/tmp/
startretries=0
autorestart=false
environment=NUM_CPUS=2
numprocs=2
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
[program:test]
command=touch /tmp/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s
directory=/tmp/
startretries=0
autorestart=false
environment=NUM_CPUS=2
numprocs=%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s ; <- note difference here
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s
```

I get this error (followed by a list of available `ENV_` variables that doesn't include `ENV_NUM_CPUS`):

```
Error: Format string '%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s' for 'program:test.numprocs' contains names ('ENV_NUM_CPUS') which cannot be expanded.
```

I want to set `numprocs` with an ENV. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here? This seems like a bug? Why does `%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s` work in two places but not the third?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the result of when the particular configuration option is processed. It looks as if supervisord uses the `numprocs` option before it has processed the `environment` option.

The simplest solution would seem to be setting `NUM_CPUS` external to supervisord, so that your config looks like:

```
[program:test]
command=touch /tmp/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s
directory=/tmp/
startretries=0
autorestart=false
numprocs=%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s ; <- note difference here
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_%(ENV_NUM_CPUS)s
```

And you start start `supervisord` with that environment variable already set:

```
NUM_CPUS=2 supervisord -c my_supervisor_config.conf
```

---

If you're curious, you can find the logic [here](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/main/supervisor/options.py#L951), where some options are read with `do_expand=False` which inhibits `%(...)s` expansions; these are presumably expanded later on after config file parsing is complete (at which point they could take advantage of environment variables defined in the configuration file).